# Define temp variable in ngFor

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-template

In my angular 5 template I'm creating table rows like so:

```
<tr *ngFor="let site of auditedLabNames">
    <th>{{ site }}</th>
    <th>{{ subnetRemediationBySite[site].Mapped }}</th>
    <th>{{ subnetRemediationBySite[site].Count }}</th>
```

I'm going to end up using that `subnetRemediationBySite[site].Mapped` value multiple times in this row.  Is there some way that I can assign that to a variable so I don't have to type out that whole thing every time?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to loop it in your component and pass it to another 'shorter' variable.

```
export class YourComponent{
     public data: any = [];

     constructor(){
        // Your subnetRemediationBySite data somewhere here...

        auditedLabNames.map(res => {
             this.data.push({
                 key1: res,
                 key2: subnetRemediationBySite[res].Mapped,
                 key3: subnetRemediationBySite[res].Count
             });
        })
     }
}
```

And in your template, you may loop it as...

```
<tr *ngFor="let site of data">
<th>{{ site.key1 }}</th>
<th>{{ site.key2 }}</th>
<th>{{ site.key3 }}</th>
```

You may adjust my code base on the structure of your code. Just get the idea.. Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I'll still need other pieces though, like `site` itself, and other parts of the dictionary.

Comment: I updated the question to make it clearer that I'll use more pieces.